# Alamofire ошибка получения данных в запросе

Tags: ios

```
Alamofire.request(
.GET,
"http://localhost:9080/feed", parameters: [:])
.responseJSON { response in
    guard response.result.isSuccess else {
    print("Error while fetching: (response.result.error)")
    return
}
```

Ошибка: Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."

Запускаю сервер на Swift, сервер работает, браузер отдает тестовые данные по пути "http://localhost:9080/feed"

```
AllowArbitraryLoads = Yes

response.result.value = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Помогло следующее:

выполнил sudo ifconfig.
Показало, что в настройках у меня прописано

inet6 fe80::61e:64ff:fef8:4c2e%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
inet 192.168.0.20 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255

Поэтому написал  192.168.0.20 (вместо localhost или 127.0.0.1)